# Passing flashvar into flex 4

Tags: adobe, mxml, flex4, flashvars

I am trying to let the user set the background color of my flex 4 app by setting the colour in the flashvars variable of the calling javascript.

However, I don't seem to be able to access the flashvars at all, the best result I can get (from trace) is **undefined**.

The javascript looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {}; 
    flashvars.firstname = "bob";
    var params = {
        menu: "false",
        scale: "noScale",
        allowFullscreen: "true",
        allowScriptAccess: "always",
        bgcolor: "#FF0000"
    };
    var attributes = {
        id:"OvaWidget"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF("myApp.swf", "altContent", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

And my mxml is

```
<fx:Script> 
    <![CDATA[
    import mx.core.FlexGlobals;

    [Bindable]
    public var firstname:String;

    protected function init():void
    {
        trace(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters[firstname]);
    }
    ]]> 
</fx:Script>

<s:Label text="Name: "/>
<s:Label text="{firstname}" fontWeight="bold"/>
```

Any ideas? All help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an flashVars-object.
So you need to change your code to this:

```
trace(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.parameters.firstname);
```